# Datatables Ajax works when reading JSON from file, but not from variable (Django)

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, datatables

I've been stuck with this problem for a few days now. I'm trying to feed JSON data to DataTables, but it only works if I use static file as source (see below index.html).

index.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydata').DataTable( {

          "ajax": {
            "url": '{% static "myapp/supplier.json" %}',  //<= works
{#                    "url": '{{ suppliers_all }}',#}     //<=does not work
            "dataSrc": ""
          },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "classification" },
            ]
    } );
} );
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    suppliers_all = Supplier.objects.all().values('name', 'classification')
    suppliers_all = json.dumps(list(suppliers_all))
    context = {'suppliers_all': suppliers_all,
               }
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

JSON output:

```
[{"classification": "Base Supplier", "name": "Supplier Name1"}, {"classification": "Strategic Supplier", "name": "Supplier Name2"}]
```

When I use django passed variable `{{ suppliers_all }}` browser debugging returns [a 404 not found error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7). I tried hardcoding JSON output according to websites examples, tried many different ways, but it will never work if it's not fetched directly from file.

**Update:**
Solved problem by creating new view with JSON Httpresponse and url

```
def supjson(request):
    suppliers_all = Supplier.objects.all().values('name', 'classification')
    suppliers_all = json.dumps(list(suppliers_all), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    context = {'suppliers_all': suppliers_all,
    return HttpResponse(suppliers_all, content_type='application/json')
```

Then changed Ajax url to the following:

```
                  "ajax": {
                    "url": '{% url 'myapp:supjson' %}',
                    "dataSrc": ""
                  },
```

While it works, I feel it's redundant solution as I have issues passing data through the variable directly.

**Update #2**: Issue was due to Django autoescaping single commas which then made JSON parsing did not work. I did the following changes:

Added mark_safe in the views.py

```
context = {'suppliers_all': mark_safe(suppliers_all),
           }
```

Stringified JSON and then Parsed it in index.html template:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var json=JSON.stringify({{ suppliers_all }});
    $('#mydata').DataTable( {
          "data": JSON.parse(json),
```

Comment: Well, you're getting a 404 because your context variable isn't really a URL resource and ajax is thinking its an actual URL.

Comment: I guess it makes sense, but is there a way to pass it in a variable? All examples always have links to a file. Do I need to generate separate url page and pass it or is there a way to do it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need to load data from url. If your data is preloaded then try to add it directly to DataTable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mydata').DataTable({
        "data": JSON.parse('{{ suppliers_all }}'),
        "columns": [
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "classification"},
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work. table would load empty and I would get [incorrect parameter error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4). I have added commas to `'{{ suppliers_all }}'` otherwise it gives syntax error. I managed to solve problem by creating new view and url with JSON output and then just linking Ajax to it, but that still feels redundant solution.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking into more details once more, and realized the issue I had was because Django render automatically escaped single commas when generating template and thats why JSON parse did not work for me earlier when I tried

Comment: Glad you find a solution :)