# Flask: Populate Data Table with variable, not file

Tags: python, json, dataframe, flask, datatables

Hello I am trying to populate a table using Flask and Data Tables- and to do it *fast*. Rendering the whole html table is too slow, so I have tried (and succeeded) using `ajax: url-to-file` and `deferRender: True`. However, I want to do it just by passing the data and with JavaScript or Ajax, in some other way- without a file.

I have tried various ways to populate the table, for example [passing a url of another route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282627/datatables-ajax-works-when-reading-json-from-file-but-not-from-variable-django), but to no result.

The only way I found to at least get the data in the template is by the following way. Unfortunately I fail to accomplish the final task of populating the table.

Route in `views.py`:

```
    @main.route('/table_display_route')
    def table_display():
        # ...
        # creating df from session items
        # ...
        columns = df.columns # for a dynamically created table

        table_json = json.dumps(json.loads(df.to_json(orient='index')))

        return render_template('display.html', columns=columns, 
                                table_json=table_json)
```

table_json is of the following form:

> "1": {   "col1": "atr1",   "col2": "atr2",   ... }, "2": {   ...etc...

Then `display.html`, rendering table headers only:

```
 ..
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {% for column in columns %}
          <th>{{ column }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
 ...
```

And the script, looking to populate the rows as follows, which doesn't work:

```
$('#display_table').find('table').DataTable( {
    data: {{ table_json }},
    // ... 
} );
```

Any suggestions?

**SOLUTION (according to selected answer, with tiny modifications):**

views.py:

```
@main.route('/table_display_route')
def table_display():
    // .. building df from session

    # get table headers and rows
    columns = df.columns
    rows = df.to_json(orient='values')

    return render_template('display.html', columns=columns, rows=rows,...)
```

display.html:

```
...
<div id="display_table">
  <table class="cell-border" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {% for column in columns %}
          <th>{{ column }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
...
```

Script:

```
// set table as DataTable
var display_table = $('#display_table').find('table').DataTable({
    ...
    deferRender: true
});

function loadTable() {
    $.get('table_display_route', function(response, status){
        var data = {{ rows }};
        display_table.clear();

        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
            // fill row
            row = data[key]

            // append to table
            display_table.row.add(row);
        });

        // Update table -- make rows visible.
        display_table.draw();
    });
}

//execute function
loadTable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `DataTables` and `Flask`, and you want to fill through a template rendering, I would recommend you incorporate a table template in the HTML directly, which is preferred by jinja2 and Flask, rather than have it done through javascript. Because you are doing a template rendering, your HTML table will automatically update with whatever your desired json data is whenever this route is used or called. Here's an example of that below:

Route in `views.py`

```
@main.route('/table_display')
def table_display():
    # ...
    # creating df from session items
    # ...
    columns = df.columns # for a dynamically created table

    table_d = df.to_json(orient='index')

    return render_template('display.html', columns=columns, 
                            table_data=table_d)
```

where the data structure of `columns` is an array of strings (columns), and `table_json` is structured as `"1": { "col1": "atr1", "col2": "atr2", ... }, "2": { ...etc...`

Layout in `display.html`

```
<table id="test-table" class="table display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for c in columns %}
                <th scope="col">{{c}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for k, v in table_data.items() %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{v.col1}}</td>
                <td>{{v.col2}}</td>
                ...
                <td>{{v.colN}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and in `text/javascript` code

```
var test_table = $('#test-table').DataTable();
```

**Edit 2018-09-11 to reflect comments**

Using just javascript without a template rendering:

Hi, how about this function:

```
var test_table = $('#test-table').DataTable({deferRender: true});

function loadTable() {
    $.get('flask_route', function(response, status){
        var data = response['data'];
        test_table.clear();

        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
            // fill row
            row = []

            // append to table
            test_table.row.add(row);
        });

        // Update table -- make rows visible.
        test_table.draw();
    });
}
```

Comment: You can test renderings like so natively in Python: https://gist.github.com/SEJeff/4207694

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, since it is rendering the html table and then redrawing it as DataTable, it is getting slow even with slightly large tables of only a few thousand lines. It is only a little faster than just passing the html table in render_template and then redrawing it as DataTable- which is really very slow and it is the reason I tried to do this with Javascript / Ajax in the first place.

Comment: The file solution I have is drawing the headers as in your solution and then it is getting the rows from a file, with Ajax. I am hoping for a solution that will draw and populate the rows from Javascript, so I don't have to use files.

Comment: How about using .add() and .draw()?